# How can I list all Spring Boot datasources?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-cloud

How can I list all Spring Boot datasources? Including ones that configured with Spring Cloud Config and others that autoconfigured being based on Maven dependencies of db drivers in pom.xml

Comment: Can you try `applicationContext.getBean(Datasource.class)` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have multiple datasources with different qualifiers , you can get it in a list. In fact not just for Datasource type , to list  of any type , you can have similar code. and this list will have all bean implementations.

```
@Autowired
List<DataSource> datasources;
```

Or you can access by bean name as well.

```
@Autowired
Map<String,DataSource> datasources;
```

Comment: How each of them can be accessed? E.g. if I need to access the certain one.

Comment: Edited my answer.